# How to freely group tabs with Tab Mix Plus

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, browser-tabs

I am using Firefox 3.5 and Tab Mix Plus ("TMP", which I want to keep).

I want an additional feature, to group tabs the way I  see them belonging together. Do you know which addon?

(I found "group/sort tabs" that groups them by date or domain, but that is not, what I want, I want my own grouping. Another one, "tab kit" does not play with TMP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TabGroups Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10254) will do the job